# Dilemma with window.onbeforeunload and image

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is my main JS file:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { 
   showME();
}

var ShowMe = function(){
    $('<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png" style="position:fixed;left:0;top:0" />').appendTo('body');
}
```

When window.onbeforeunload gets called (i.e user navigating away from the page) ShowMe() gets executed but I do not see the image on the page.

However if you run showMe() in your console the image will show.

This is happening in all non-FireFox Browsers. Firefox seems to work fine.

Comment: maybe it is happening due to the fact that on window unload the request to the image is stopped? how about trying to to an alert before / after the image to see what of that code piece is really executed as an alert stops the browser

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I did a console.log('before') and console.log('after') and both get called. In fact, when I look at the DOM i see the image get attached to the body, it just doesn't get rendered for some reason.

Comment: is it `in action` somewhere so I can take a deeper look?

Comment: I know I'm a bit late to the party, but the problem can be solved by performing the image insertion in an event instead, using setTimeout with a time of 0 (or leave it out, as 0 is default).